# Is it in spec to have hidden services until after securely paired in Bluetooth Low Energy?

Tags: bluetooth, embedded, iot, bluetooth-lowenergy

Working on a BLE application in which I do not want to expose certain services until I am securely paired/bonded to a valid device.  The problem is that during discovery, it seems that all primary services are exposed to the client in order for it to finalize the connection.  Is there anyway to hide some services until a later time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may dynamically change contents of the GATT database while connected. GATT service and GATT "Service Changed" characteristic will be used to notify client of such changes ([Vol 3, Part G], 7.1).

Hiding service before bonding does not add anything useful wrt having a service with authenticated access only. In both cases, you'll need to bond to use it, but managing access rights rather than handling GATT db change is better tested in implementations (if supported at all).

So yes, in theory, you may change service exposed in your GATT db once bonded, but I'd rather not rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use standard profiles, I don't think so. Only solution that I could imagine would be custom profile that encapsulate data that you don't want to expose. Even in this case UUIDs will be visible.